# Hide the Vimeo Play/Pause button?

Tags: iframe, vimeo

I am embedding a Vimeo video into my site using Vimeo iframe.

In Vimeo I have disable all the features.. thumb, title, volume etc. But I am unable to disable the Play/Pause button that sits in the middle of the video.

Because I am using the vimeo video as a background video I want to hide the Play/Pause button.

Is there away using jQuery perhaps to find the button then hide it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Starting a video automatically and not giving the user a way to stop it is an invitation to the back button.  You can expect a high bounce rate.  Why would you want to do ths?

Comment: Because someone has to move forward. Short, looping full-bleed background clips have a very high impact on the overall experience. It could be argued that without this you can expect a high boredom rate.

Comment: Answers are locked but there _is_ a way to do this. I'm not sure if it only works on the Pro plan (I am using Pro), but you can add the `GET` parameter `background=1` to the iframe src. This enables autoplay/loop, mutes the audio, and removes ALL UI elements from the iframe. It's probably exactly what you need, although for some reason it's not documented and is also no available as an option in the old or new JS APIs.

Answer (score 3):

I've been investigating this issue lately, and I think the answer is no. Basically, the Vimeo embedding options does not support disabling the play/pause button. If you could communicate with the player's iframe, you could insert a  tag with some CSS rules to disable it. But you can't. You could, if the iframe was programmed by you and you added a listener for a cross-domain communication (like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro). But the Vimeo player iframe doesn't have that, for obvious security reasons.

In the Vimeo forums (https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:37769), a Vimeo staff member said one year ago:

> Hey folks,
>   If you're a PRO member, you can use a third party player that supports the removal of all player chrome: vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#how-do-i-use-a-third-party-player-with-vimeo-pro
>   Vimeo's player will not be removing the Play/Pause button.

So, basically, your/my only option is to go PRO and use a third party player, or to develop your own (which is the equivalent of not using Vimeo at all, and the only thing Vimeo will provide you with is the hosting of the video files, as far as I understand).